# Reusing LESS nested styles

Tags: less

Let's say that I have a style defined using Less:

```
ul.unstyled,
ol.unstyled {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Later on, I want to re-use the `unstyled` class:

```
.my-list {
  .unstyled;
}
```

This doesn't work, however, and I can't figure out the magic to make it work.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't re-use arbitrary class definitions, only mixins (those starting with a dot). In this case you'll need to duplicate it.

Comment: does this imply that LESS creates a parameterless mixin when you define `.myClass`?

Comment: Good question. I think yes, because according to the documentation mixins are just classes: "Mixins allow you to embed all the properties of a class into another class by simply including the class name as one of its properties. It’s just like variables, but for whole classes".

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
.unstyled {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-list {
  .unstyled;
}
```

You won't be able to nest `.unstyled` if it's defined as `ul.unstled` and `ol.unstyled`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me because I don't own the original definition... in other words, the `unstyled` class is defined in `Bootstrap.less` and I'd like to avoid tweaking the dependency.  Instead, I want to know how to reuse a nested style.

Comment: Ah. If you don't/can't override those styles I'm not sure you'll be able to reuse it the way you want to. LESS doesn't let you specify ``ul.unstyled`` or the like as a nested class. You could always create a mixin, but that would be duplicating the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't reuse `.unstyled` when it's a nested style and you probably don't want to edit the Bootstrap source code, I'd suggest you just assign both classnames to your list:

```
<ul class="unstyled my-list" />
```